# removing direct duplicates on a list

Tags: haskell

So i am supposed to remove direct duplicates that are next to each other from a list. For example 1,3,3,3,2,4,4,2,4] = [1,3,2,4,2,4] or [63,65,65,64,65,63,65,65,64,64,65] = [63,65,64,65,63,65,64,65]. My code just removes all duplicates. I think my problem is that i compare with elem and i need a function that only compares with the next element.

```
module Blueprint where
import Prelude

compress :: [Int] -> [Int]
compress [] = []
compress (x:xs)   | x `elem` xs   = compress xs
                  | otherwise     = x : compress xs
```

Comment: It would help to pattern match the two leading elements of the list with `compress (x1:x2:xs)` and then check if they are equal. If they are, then you can create the new list without `x2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right now you are checking if x has a duplicate in the rest of the function. You actually want to check if the next element is a duplicate. You can do this by looking at the first two elements of a list not just the first one.

```
compress :: [Int] -> [Int]
compress [] = []
compress [x] = [x]
compress (x:x2:xs) | x == x2   = compress (x2:xs)
                   | otherwise = x : compress (x2:xs)
```

Comment: got a parse error and figured that i have to put the constructors in "()" works great thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The `group` function finds adjacent equal values and groups them together. So your function may be implemented as

```
compress = map head . group
```

At first, it may look dangerous to use `head`; however, a promise of `group` is that each element it returns is a non-empty list.

Answer (score 1):

I've been getting a lot of bang from this little fold technique lately:

```
smash :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
smash xs = foldr go (`seq` []) xs Nothing
  where
    go x r (Just prev)
      | x == prev = r (Just x)
    go x r _ = x : r (Just x)
```

Comment: I got a kick out of figuring this one out. Thanks for the fun! :)